# Java Overriding equals and hashCode advice

Tags: java

I have a thought on attempting to override equals/hashCode on a slew of objects I am creating and developing an interface/utility class for doing this using Java 1.7.  Since I am unsure of how this approach will perform I would appreciate any feedback. My primary concern is using autoboxing with primitive types and what kind of performance hits I will take.

Interface:

```
public interface Hashable {

/**
 * Return the base offset for the {@link Object#hashCode()}, this number
 * should be unique and odd;
 * 
 * @return int
 */
public int getBaseOffset();

/**
 * Return the base offset for the class fields{@link Object#hashCode()},
 * this number should be unique and odd;
 * 
 * @return int
 */
public int getFieldOffset();

/**
 * Return an {@link Object} array of the fields to use for
 * {@link Object#equals(Object)} and {@link Object#hashCode()}
 * 
 * @return {@link Object} array
 */
public Object[] getHashFields();
}
```

Utility Class:

```
public class HashUtil {

    /**
     * This method will create a hash code based on the
     * {@link Hashable#getHashFields()}. If the object is immutable this method
     * only needs to be called once through lazy initialization, otherwise the
     * class can call out to it through the {@link Object#hashCode()} override.
     * <p>
     * <b>Example:</b>
     * 
     * <pre>
     * public int hashCode() {
     *     return HashUtil.createHash(this);
     * }
     * <p>
     * @param hashable
     *            {@link Object} implementing {@link Hashable} interface
     * @return int
     * to use for hash code
     */
    public static int createHash(Hashable hashable) {
        HashCodeBuilder builder = new HashCodeBuilder(hashable.getBaseOffset(), hashable.getFieldOffset());

        for (Object o : hashable.getHashFields()) {
            if (o != null) {
            builder.append(o);
            }
        }
        return builder.toHashCode();
    }

    /**
     * Evaluates whether two {@link Hashable} objects are equal. This method is
     * intended for use when overriding {@link Object#equals(Object)}.
     * <p>
     * <b>Example:</b>
     * 
     * <pre>
     * public boolean equals(Object o) {
     *     return HashUtil.equals(this, o);
     * }
     * <p>
     * @param h1 first {@link Hashable} to compare
     * @param h2 second {@link Hashable} to compare
     * @return true if they are equal
     */
    public static boolean equals(Hashable h1, Hashable h2) {
        if (h1.getHashFields() == null || h2.getHashFields() == null) {
            if (!(h1.getHashFields() == null && h2.getHashFields() == null)) {
            return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        if (h1.getHashFields().length != h2.getHashFields().length) {
            return false;
        }
        EqualsBuilder builder = new EqualsBuilder();
        for (int x = 0; x < h1.getHashFields().length; x++) {
            Object o1 = h1.getHashFields()[x];
            Object o2 = h2.getHashFields()[x];
            builder.append(o1, o2);
        }
        return builder.isEquals();
    }
}
```

Comment: apache commons library offer `HashcodeBuilder` and `EqualsBuilder` that can be useful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trust me. Dont write you own hashing/equals logic.

Use already available and tested code like Apache [EqualsBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/EqualsBuilder.html) and [HashCodeBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html)

E.g:

```
public int hashCode() {
     // you pick a hard-coded, randomly chosen, non-zero, odd number
     // ideally different for each class
     return new HashCodeBuilder(17, 37).
       append(name).
       append(age).
       toHashCode();
   }


public boolean equals(Object obj) {
   // do you basic object check first
   // then delegate to equalsbuilder
   MyClass rhs = (MyClass) obj;
   return new EqualsBuilder()
                 .append(name, rhs.name)
                 .append(age, rhs.age)
                 .isEquals();
  }
```

Comment: Do you have any links that I can read as to why this is a bad idea? I have written my own hash/equals logic a few times and have seen some pretty good performance increases. Provided I *know* what kind of lookup profile I'm expecting, what's the problem? I ask sincerely, as I'd like to make sure I haven't fallen into a trap somewhere without realising...

Comment: Unless you have very specific performance gain, you should use the Apache ones. Mainly for the following reasons: a) Apache Builders are heavily tested and used b) People who see the code will immediately know what's happening c) Writing a perfect hashcode can be a convoluted job and people often get it wrong. I always say "Dont code it until you really need it"

Comment: Thanks Suraj. I was searching for a utility like this when I started.

Comment: You can also use the [@EqualsAndHashCode](http://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode.html) annotation from Lombok with quite a wide range of objects to get `equals()` and `hashCode()` with just a single line of code.